# Is there a way to create a convertor or deserializer for JSON of this format for Retrofit / Android

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

I have used Retrofit with simple objects but this current project has been giving me a headache. I am trying to parse information on a golf course.

What would be the best approach if your api response looks something like:

```
    [  
   {  
  "course_id":"1",
  "name":"Prompton State Park",
  "city":"Honesdale",
  "state":"PA",
  "country":"United States",
  "reviews":"9",
  "rating":"3.72",
  "tee_1_clr":"FFFF00",
  "tee_2_clr":"FF0000",
  "tee_3_clr":"",
  "tee_4_clr":"",
  "dgcr_url":"https:\/\/www.dgcoursereview.com\/course.php?id=1",
  "dgcr_mobile_url":"https:\/\/www.dgcoursereview.com\/mobile\/course.php?
   id=1",
"rating_img":"https:\/\/www.dgcoursereview.com\/images\/rating\/discs_3.5.png",
  "rating_img_small":"https:\/\/www.dgcoursereview.com\/images\/rating\/discs_sm_3.5.png"
},
{  
  "hole_num":"1",
  "hole_lbl":"1",
  "tee_1_len":"324",
  "tee_2_len":"436",
  "tee_3_len":"0",
  "tee_4_len":"0",
  "tee_1_par":"3",
  "tee_2_par":"3",
  "tee_3_par":"0",
  "tee_4_par":"0"
},
{  
  "hole_num":"2",
  "hole_lbl":"2",
  "tee_1_len":"282",
  "tee_2_len":"390",
  "tee_3_len":"0",
  "tee_4_len":"0",
  "tee_1_par":"3",
  "tee_2_par":"4",
  "tee_3_par":"0",
  "tee_4_par":"0"
},
{  
  "hole_num":"3",
  "hole_lbl":"3",
  "tee_1_len":"352",
  "tee_2_len":"376",
  "tee_3_len":"0",
  "tee_4_len":"0",
  "tee_1_par":"3",
  "tee_2_par":"3",
  "tee_3_par":"0",
  "tee_4_par":"0"
},
{  
  "hole_num":"4",
  "hole_lbl":"4",
  "tee_1_len":"258",
  "tee_2_len":"319",
  "tee_3_len":"0",
  "tee_4_len":"0",
  "tee_1_par":"3",
  "tee_2_par":"3",
  "tee_3_par":"0",
  "tee_4_par":"0"
},
{  
  "hole_num":"5",
  "hole_lbl":"5",
  "tee_1_len":"188",
  "tee_2_len":"262",
  "tee_3_len":"0",
  "tee_4_len":"0",
  "tee_1_par":"3",
  "tee_2_par":"3",
  "tee_3_par":"0",
  "tee_4_par":"0"
},
{  
  "hole_num":"6",
  "hole_lbl":"6",
  "tee_1_len":"245",
  "tee_2_len":"364",
  "tee_3_len":"0",
  "tee_4_len":"0",
  "tee_1_par":"3",
  "tee_2_par":"3",
  "tee_3_par":"0",
  "tee_4_par":"0"
},
{  
  "hole_num":"7",
  "hole_lbl":"7",
  "tee_1_len":"239",
  "tee_2_len":"282",
  "tee_3_len":"0",
  "tee_4_len":"0",
  "tee_1_par":"3",
  "tee_2_par":"3",
  "tee_3_par":"0",
  "tee_4_par":"0"
},
{  
  "hole_num":"8",
  "hole_lbl":"8",
  "tee_1_len":"409",
  "tee_2_len":"508",
  "tee_3_len":"0",
  "tee_4_len":"0",
  "tee_1_par":"3",
  "tee_2_par":"4",
  "tee_3_par":"0",
  "tee_4_par":"0"
},
{  
  "hole_num":"9",
  "hole_lbl":"9",
  "tee_1_len":"255",
  "tee_2_len":"301",
  "tee_3_len":"0",
  "tee_4_len":"0",
  "tee_1_par":"3",
  "tee_2_par":"3",
  "tee_3_par":"0",
  "tee_4_par":"0"
},
{  
  "hole_num":"10",
  "hole_lbl":"10",
  "tee_1_len":"446",
  "tee_2_len":"555",
  "tee_3_len":"0",
  "tee_4_len":"0",
  "tee_1_par":"3",
  "tee_2_par":"3",
  "tee_3_par":"0",
  "tee_4_par":"0"
},
{  
  "hole_num":"11",
  "hole_lbl":"11",
  "tee_1_len":"416",
  "tee_2_len":"750",
  "tee_3_len":"0",
  "tee_4_len":"0",
  "tee_1_par":"3",
  "tee_2_par":"4",
  "tee_3_par":"0",
  "tee_4_par":"0"
},
{  
  "hole_num":"12",
  "hole_lbl":"12",
  "tee_1_len":"266",
  "tee_2_len":"393",
  "tee_3_len":"0",
  "tee_4_len":"0",
  "tee_1_par":"3",
  "tee_2_par":"3",
  "tee_3_par":"0",
  "tee_4_par":"0"
},
{  
  "hole_num":"13",
  "hole_lbl":"13",
  "tee_1_len":"603",
  "tee_2_len":"956",
  "tee_3_len":"0",
  "tee_4_len":"0",
  "tee_1_par":"3",
  "tee_2_par":"5",
  "tee_3_par":"0",
  "tee_4_par":"0"
},
{  
  "hole_num":"14",
  "hole_lbl":"14",
  "tee_1_len":"345",
  "tee_2_len":"445",
  "tee_3_len":"0",
  "tee_4_len":"0",
  "tee_1_par":"3",
  "tee_2_par":"3",
  "tee_3_par":"0",
  "tee_4_par":"0"
},
{  
  "hole_num":"15",
  "hole_lbl":"15",
  "tee_1_len":"363",
  "tee_2_len":"556",
  "tee_3_len":"0",
  "tee_4_len":"0",
  "tee_1_par":"3",
  "tee_2_par":"3",
  "tee_3_par":"0",
  "tee_4_par":"0"
},
{  
  "hole_num":"16",
  "hole_lbl":"16",
  "tee_1_len":"277",
  "tee_2_len":"383",
  "tee_3_len":"0",
  "tee_4_len":"0",
  "tee_1_par":"3",
  "tee_2_par":"3",
  "tee_3_par":"0",
  "tee_4_par":"0"
},
{  
  "hole_num":"17",
  "hole_lbl":"17",
  "tee_1_len":"288",
  "tee_2_len":"553",
  "tee_3_len":"0",
  "tee_4_len":"0",
  "tee_1_par":"3",
  "tee_2_par":"4",
  "tee_3_par":"0",
  "tee_4_par":"0"
},
{  
  "hole_num":"18",
  "hole_lbl":"18",
  "tee_1_len":"307",
  "tee_2_len":"372",
  "tee_3_len":"0",
  "tee_4_len":"0",
  "tee_1_par":"3",
  "tee_2_par":"3",
  "tee_3_par":"0",
  "tee_4_par":"0"
}
]
```

And my Object at the moment for it is

```
private String name;
private String city;
private String state;
private int holes;
private int courseId;
private String dgcrMobileLink;
private int reviewCount;
private double rating;
private double latitude;
private double longitude;

private String teeOneColor;
private Boolean teeOneExists;
public ArrayList<Hole> teeOneHoles;


private String teeTwoColor;
private Boolean teeTwoExists;
private ArrayList<Hole> teeTwoHoles;


private String teeThreeColor;
private Boolean teeThreeExists;
private ArrayList<Hole> teeThreeHoles;


private String teeFourColor;
private Boolean teeFourExists;
private ArrayList<Hole> teeFourHoles;
```

In the first run of the app I used custom loaders to parse through the JSON. Is there a way to tell retrofit how to handle the JSON format..? Or is there a better way of approaching this?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different objects in the same array. So to keep things simple I'd just have a model class containing both:

```
public class GolfInfo {
    private int course_id;
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String country;
    private int reviews;
    private float rating;
    private String tee_1_clr;
    private String tee_2_clr;
    private String tee_3_clr;
    private String tee_4_clr;
    private String dgcr_url;
    private String dgcr_mobile_url;
    private String rating_img;
    private String rating_img_small;

    private int hole_num;
    private int hole_lbl;
    private int tee_1_len;
    private int tee_2_len;
    private int tee_3_len;
    private int tee_4_len;
    private int tee_1_par;
    private int tee_2_par;
    private int tee_3_par;
    private int tee_4_par;

    // getters
}
```

I'm assuming you use Gson to deserialize your data. Now you can simply do the usual

```
Call<List<GolfInfo>> getGolfInfo();
```

When you get the data, you know for sure that the first element of the list will contain the course_id, name, city, etc. And the rest of the elements will contain hole_num, tee_1_len, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You basically have two data types - a course and then a hole . The course has an array of holes. You can use GSON to deserialize/serialize this data.

You can use a tool like this to generate your model classes

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/